# Expression parsing (arithmetic operators only)

Tags: javascript, math-expression-eval

As a self-learning project, I wrote an expression parser using the shunting yard algorithm in JavaScript. It's a larger part of what I plan to be a program for handling dice expressions in tabletop games, like 2d6 (2 six-sided dice).

I know a parsing library would be a better fit, but this is also a self-learning project for me, so I'd rather stick to implementing it myself.

My original implementation had functions `jcontains` and `jpeek` on the array prototype. I decided to refactor those out and now have assignments on arrays I create. But now I have functions like `evaluate` setting up functions on arrays. It seems to break SRP but maybe I'm being pedantic.

```
var exprjs = (function (my) {
    "use strict";
    var jcontains = function (value, propertyName) {
            if (propertyName) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                    if (value === this[i][propertyName]) return this[i];
                }
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                    if (value === this[i]) return this[i];
                }
            }
        },
        jpeek = function () {
            return this[this.length - 1];
        },
        operators = [
            {
                oper: '+', precedence: 1, associativity: 'left', func: function (a, b) {
                    trigger(this.oper, b, a); 
                    return b + a;
                }
            },
            {
                oper: '-', precedence: 1, associativity: 'left', func: function (a, b) {
                    trigger(this.oper, b, a); 
                    return b - a;
                }
            },
            {
                oper: '*', precedence: 2, associativity: 'left', func: function (a, b) {
                    trigger(this.oper, b, a);
                    return b * a;
                }
            },
            {
                oper: '/', precedence: 2, associativity: 'left', func: function (a, b) {
                    trigger(this.oper, b, a);
                    if (a === 0) { 
                        throw new Error('Divide by 0, attempted to divide ' + b + ' by ' + a);
                    }
                    return b / a;
                }
            },
            {
                oper: '^', precedence: 3, associativity: 'right', func: function (a, b) {
                    trigger(this.oper, b, a);
                    return Math.pow(b, a); 
                }
            }
        ],
        listeners = {}, 
        trigger = function(oper, b, a) {
            if (listeners[oper]) {
                listeners[oper].forEach(function(func) { 
                    func(b, a);
                }); 
            }
        },
        addListener = function(oper, func) {
            if (listeners[oper]) {
                listeners[oper].push(func); 
            } else {
                listeners[oper] = [ func ]; 
            }
        },
        exprParse = function (input) {
            var expr = typeof input === 'function' ? input() : input,
                operStack = [],
                output = [],
                numberRegexp = /[\d\.]/,
                readToken = function (input) {
                    var workingToken = '',
                        oper = '',
                        isOper = function (input) {
                            return operators.jcontains(input, 'oper');
                        },
                        handleOperator = function (input) {
                            var peeked = operStack.jpeek(),
                                lowerPrecedence = function () {
                                    return (input.precedence <= peeked.precedence) || (input.associativity === 'right' &&
                                        input.precedence < peeked.precedence);
                                };

                            while (peeked && lowerPrecedence()) {
                                output.push(operStack.pop());
                                peeked = operStack[operStack.length - 1];
                            }
                            operStack.push(input);
                            expr = expr.slice(1);
                        },
                        handleParens = function (input) {
                            if (input[0] == '(') {
                                operStack.push(input[0]);
                            }

                            if (input[0] == ')') {
                                var peeked = operStack.jpeek();
                                while (peeked !== '(') {
                                    output.push(operStack.pop());
                                    peeked = operStack.jpeek();
                                }
                                operStack.pop();
                            }
                            expr = expr.slice(1);
                        };

                    // Operator?
                    if (oper = isOper(input[0])) {
                        handleOperator(oper);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Parentheses?
                    if (input[0] == '(' || input[0] == ')') {
                        handleParens(input[0]);
                        return;
                    }

                    //Number?
                    for (var i = 0; i < input.length + 1; i++) {
                        if (input[i] && input[i].search(numberRegexp) !== -1) {
                            workingToken = workingToken.concat(input[i]);
                        } else {
                            output.push(+workingToken);
                            expr = expr.slice(i);
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    throw new Error("Unexpected value in expression.");
                };

            operStack.jcontains = jcontains; 
            operStack.jpeek = jpeek; 

            while (expr.length > 0) {
                readToken(expr);
            }

            while (operStack.length > 0) {
                output.push(operStack.pop());
            }

            output.reverse();
            return output;
        },
        evaluate = function (input) {
            var workingStack = [],
                workingToken,
                inputStack = exprParse(input);

            inputStack.jpeek = jpeek; 
            inputStack.jcontains = jcontains;

            while (!!((workingToken = inputStack.jpeek()) + (workingToken === 0))) {
                if (workingToken.func) {
                    workingStack.push(workingToken.func(workingStack.pop(), workingStack.pop()));
                    inputStack.pop();
                } else {
                    workingStack.push(inputStack.pop());
                }
            }
            return workingStack[0];
        };

    listeners.jpeek = jpeek; 
    listeners.jcontains = jcontains; 
    operators.jpeek = jpeek; 
    operators.jcontains = jcontains;

    my.evaluate = evaluate;
    my.addListener = addListener;
    return my;
}(exprjs || {}));
```